# ASP.NET MVC 4 API's endpoint not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am new to ASP.NET MVC4 and I have an issue I can't manage to resolve.

I have a simple GET endpoint which I want to return all the `prestations`.

When I try to reach this endpoint, I get no response and not even a timeout. My API is working well in other endpoints.

Here is the code inside the method related to this endpoint:

```
[Route("api/Prestations")]
// GET: api/Prestations
/// <summary>
/// Liste de toutes les prestations
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Prestation>))]
public List<Prestation> GetPrestations()
{
    return db.Prestations.ToList();
}
```

I simply can't see why this is not working.

Some help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you configure route for this action? Please show full controller class

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside the method?  Perhaps its taking a VERY long time to get your data from the database.  Just how many rows are being returned?

Comment: Remove your line of code to get the `Prestations`, and replace it with a `throw new Exception();`.  Is the exception thrown?

Comment: @Amy The exception is thrown. I have edited my post to add the route definition.

Comment: Okay that confirms the issue is in EF, or in the size of the data you're trying to serialize.  So undo the exception change, assign the result `db.Prestations.ToList()` to a variable, return that variable.  Set a breakpoint.  Does `db.Prestations.ToList()` return at all, or is that where it is stalled?

Comment: @Amy Okay. If I assign the result to a variable and throw an Exception before the return point, the Exception is thrown.

Comment: Then it is the amount of data you are returning.  It's too much.  Return less data.

Comment: How can I do this please ? Should I return only the half of my list in this method and create a second method that is returning this prestations list from the middle ?

Comment: You have different options.  Does `Prestation` have sub-objects hanging off of it?  One option is to remove non-essential data or child objects.  Another option is to use paging.

Comment: Yes, ```Prestation``` does have sub-objects. How do I remove them from the select please ?

Comment: I mean from the ```db.Prestations.ToList()``` ?

Answer (score 2):

According to this article [Handling Larger JSON String Values in .NET and Avoiding Exceptions](http://rion.io/2013/04/28/handling-larger-json-string-values-in-net-and-avoiding-exceptions/) you can try to increase the size of JSON string that you return by changing the web.config:

```
<configuration>  
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090" />
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Also you can try to serialize the result with [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and return as a content to see if it works.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Prestation>))]
public ActionResult GetPrestations()
{
    var presentations = db.Prestations.ToList();
    return Content(JsonConvert.Seriazlize(presentations), "application/json");
}
```

But in general you would't want to return data from entire table to the client because it can be huge and contain millions of records. So you would rather implement pagination:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Prestation>))]
public List<Prestation> GetPrestations(int skip = 0, int take = 100)
{
    return db.Prestations.OrderBy(p => p.IdPrestation).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer :)

Comment: Though, if I implement pagination, should I request my endpoint with adding skip and take parameters to URL ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière, yes, you request a first batch of, say, 100 items, then you query next 100 by skipping 100 and taking next 100 and so on. Also make sure to sort items by ID to ensure consistent ordering. AFAIR in EF 6.x it is required to define a sort order to such queries.

Answer (score 0):

I finally went over the solution, I had to create a ViewModel to return the list and put only the Name of the prestations and the Id.

Here's my newly created class:

```
public class PrestationResultNormal
{
    public List<ItemPrestation> prestations;


    public PrestationResultNormal(List<Prestation> prestations)
    {
        this.prestations = prestations.Select(x => new ItemPrestation()
        {
            IdPrestation = x.IdPrestation,
            NomPrestation = x.NomPrestation
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help ! :)

and now in my method, I do:

```
var prestations = db.Prestations.ToList();

return new PrestationResultNormal(prestations);
```

Comment: I think this is only a tricky workaround which solves your problem. Would be nice if you can attach the screenshot which shows the Network content when you run the query to see the details of the request to the API. If you use Chrome then you can simply click F12 to open developer tools, and then open the Network tab, then send the request to your api and make a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.ActionName(nameof(GetPrestations))]
public HttpResponseMessage GetPrestations()
{
            // var result db.Prestations.ToList();
            var result = new List<Prestations>()
        {
            new Prestations(){
                IdPrestation = 3,
                NomPrestation = "blah1"
            },
            new Prestations(){
                IdPrestation = 4,
                NomPrestation = "blah2"
            }
        };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}

public class Prestations
{
    public int IdPrestation { get; set; }

    public string NomPrestation { get; set; }
}
```

If the above code works for you then try to uncomment the `var result db.Prestations.ToList();` and use it instead. Both things should work.

Answer (score 0):

If data is huge and loading is causing not working then remove `.ToList()` from the return `db.Prestations.ToList();` as return `db.Prestations;` this will avoid execution of loading data as defer while looping in view (If you are using this Model in a view).